# is child process can run different program after fork() call?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

A parent process creates a child process by calling the fork() system call. Both the parent and
child processes run the same program as fork creates an exact copy of the parent process. Is it
possible for the child process to run some other program? If yes then how, if no then why?

Comment: Look up `execv` commands

Answer (score 0):

You can have different implementations in child and parent as fork() retuns 0 to child component and process id of child to parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void forkexample()
{
    // child process because return value zero
    if (fork() == 0)
        printf("Hello from Child!\n");
  
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    else
        printf("Hello from Parent!\n");
}
int main()
{
    forkexample();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but  it is in the same program then how child run the different program

Comment: Fork() creates a different process altogether. So, the function name will be the same, but it will be called in a different process. Hence, you can execute different logics.